# How to specify ORDER BY when using DELETE FROM in combination with OUTPUT?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I use the query below to get the next item of a specific type from my table.
I chose this query format to prevent racing conditions if several servers try to get the next item.
Question: how can I get the item that has the lowest dtmLastRunDate? I tried to add an "ORDER BY dtmLastRunDate" but it gives me "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'".

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM Schedule
WITH (READPAST)
OUTPUT DELETED.intUserID, DELETED.dtmLastRunDate
WHERE intScheduleType = @intScheduleType
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it into a CTE as below.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP(1) *
         FROM   Schedule WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
         WHERE  intScheduleType = @intScheduleType
         ORDER  BY dtmLastRunDate)
DELETE FROM T
OUTPUT DELETED.intUserID,
       DELETED.dtmLastRunDate
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what the ROWLOCK, READPAST attributes are doing in this context? Also does that make sure that no other server also selects the same row before it gets deleted? I don't really see the difference to selecting into a TEMP table?

Comment: @Krumelur - `rowlock` should be reasonably self explanatory from the name. `readpast` means that under concurrency a second transaction won't get blocked waiting for the first transaction's lock to be released. See [Using tables as Queues: FIFO Queues section](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) for more detail. No idea why you are talking about temp tables. These are entirely different from CTEs. A CTE does not get materialised into any sort of temporary table.

Comment: The link is great explanation thanks! But it also shows that the problem can be solved without a CTE (last paragraph in the FIFO section). Do I understand correctly that the alternative version is just more expensive but as secure with regards to concurrency?

Comment: @Krumelur - Yes. The sub query one does quite a lot more work to achieve the same result.